# Eclipse 'Quick Fix' Will not Open

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I recently discovered that I need to perform a 'quick fix' on a mavenised project I have. I was able to perform this quick fix at work, however when I right click on my home laptop, the quick fix window does not open. I am using Eclipse Luna for Mac (whereas at work I have Eclipse Keplar - Windows). I cannot force the quick fix window to open by using the short-cut keys - nor can I access it via the 'edit --> quick fix' menu option.

I need to access quick fix and select 'Exclude the associated raw classpath entry from the set of potential publish/export dependencies.'

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[image: Quick Fix option is enabled]

Heres the log from eclipse:
    !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-05-19 20:32:45.263
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:499)
        at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.executeItem(HandledContributionItem.java:825)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(HandledContributionItem.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem.access$6(HandledContributionItem.java:685)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.HandledContributionItem$4.handleEvent(HandledContributionItem.java:613)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4188)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1490)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1475)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1279)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4031)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3658)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.QuickFixHandler.execute(QuickFixHandler.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:479)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:374)
        at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.ProgressMonitorDialog.run(ProgressMonitorDialog.java:527)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$RunnableWithStatus.run(ProgressManager.java:1380)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager$5.run(ProgressManager.java:1214)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4721)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.ProgressManager.runInUI(ProgressManager.java:1211)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.progress.WorkbenchSiteProgressService.runInUI(WorkbenchSiteProgressService.java:396)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.QuickFixHandler.execute(QuickFixHandler.java:124)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.registry.MarkerHelpRegistry.getResolutions(MarkerHelpRegistry.java:254)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.views.markers.QuickFixHandler$1.run(QuickFixHandler.java:88)
        at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:466)
        ... 58 more

Comment: Are there any errors in the error log?

Comment: hi Alex, yes I just looked. Without pasting the whole error that is thrown, Ill show the beginning: !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2015-05-19 20:32:45.263
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:247)
        at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:229)
...

Comment: We'll need the whole stack, stick it in the question as code.

Comment: I've got nothing, the only things I can suggest is to try a different JRE, try a different copy of eclipse and try flushing the eclipse plugin cache by starting with the -clean argument.